# Microsoft Excel - Formula for Date change in one cell, changes different cells data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to have an individual cell change other cell's values based on date.

Realizing that my attempted formula is way off, I am hoping someone can assist me in correcting this.

Here is my theoretical formula to give an idea of what I am trying to do with some corresponding images.

Formula:  `=IF(Sheet1!A2:A20=Sheet2!B2, "Sheet1!B2:B20", "Incorrect Date")`

Sheet2:
[image]

Sheet1:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP` instead of `IF`, that's the right function here:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,SHEET1!A:B,2,FALSE),"Incorrect Date")`

Comment: Mate, Thank you so much!  That works great.  I do have one follow up issue though, when a date is input that does not exist on "sheet1" (i.e. 10/1/2015) it does not list as "Incorrect Date" but instead provides the previous value.  (i.e. 10/1/2015 = 4.16).  If this becomes too difficult to alter I can work with what was provided.  Thank you so much again.

Comment: I've missed a parameter, it should be ok now.

Comment: Absolutely.  Sorry for the 1 additional follow up.  Is there anyway to bracket it so it is just between those specific cells.  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A2:A20:B2:B20,2,FALSE),"Incorrect Date")

Comment: Bracketing is fine, just your reference is too long, use `Sheet1!A2:B20`